# How can I install a non-notarized application that is not in the App Store and not from a verified developer?

Tags: install, catalina, gatekeeper, notarization

Is there a possibility to install software that was not "notarized" for macOS Catalina? I have an application that worked on macOS Mojave but cannot be installed anymore on macOS Catalina. I think the developers must "notarize" this software. Checking with spctl -a -vv my.app confirmed that it is **rejected**.

1. What can an end user do about it to install it anyway until this process is finished?

Comment: I'm still able to right-click --> open which presents the option to open along with a cancel option, as in Mojave.

Comment: I don't think that this will ever be removed because notarization has an expire date build in. So this would make old apps worthless. But hey, we live in capitalism and when huge corporations find a way to force you on spending, the government will do nothing to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In macOS 10.14 and 10.15, when an app fails to install because it hasn’t been notarized or is from an unidentified developer, it will appear in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy**, under the **General** tab. Click **Open Anyway** to confirm your intent to open or install the app.

See [Safely open apps on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) from Apple Support.

Comment: Or, disable SIP (and family) if that's still possible?